# How could I turn my Mac OS back on, if it doesn't turn on with the power button?

Tags: macos, power, kernel-panic

So my Mac OS has had several kernel panics throughout the day, and it all started yesterday April 7th, 2020 in the afternoon. I use Macintosh HD. As of right now at 9:22 PM my Mac OS won't turn on. How can I get it back on and stop the kernel panics??

Comment: What model of mac (iMac, MacBook Pro etc) do you have and what year was it made?

Comment: I believe it's an iMac and I had it since 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a guide to triage when a Mac wont start, so I typically am methodical to read each step, perform them all in order - one by one.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204267

When it says unplug all accessories, you do have to do all of them, even Apple accessories or things you know work since a good keyboard can still cause a failing USB controller in the Mac to malfunction. If you can get Your Mac to start after isolating it and still it panics before you can log in or get work done, follow the steps for a blank screen.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210905